# Change values in Datatable based on input type=checkbox checked change event without runat attribute

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

Here I have added some dynamic input type="checkbox" with dynamic id's .I want to change the Unchecked values in my datatable to checked if the specific checkbox is checked.Kindly Help.Thanks in Advance

```
//Here is my aspx page code
     <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
        <table border="1">
            <thead>

                <%string j = " Check"; %>
                <%for (int i = 0; i < 10;i++ )
                  {%>


                <th style="padding:2px; width:500px;">Table Head<br /><br />

                  <%
                      CheckBox chk = new CheckBox();
                      chk.ID = i + j;
                      chk.Text = "I am " + i + j; 
                       %> 
                <input type="checkbox" id="<%=i+j%>" value="<%=i+j %>" />
                    <label for="<%=i+j%>"><%=i+j %></label>



                </th>


                <%} %>

            </thead>
        </table>
            <asp:Button runat="server" Text="Click Me" OnClick="Unnamed_Click"/>
        </div>
        </form>
    //Here is my .cs page code
     protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


                  dt_ViewAccessLog.Columns.Add("appId");
                  dt_ViewAccessLog.Columns.Add("Empcode");
                  dt_ViewAccessLog.Columns.Add("Status");
                  for (int i = 0; i < 10;i++ ) 
                  {

                      dt_ViewAccessLog.Rows.Add("App Id", i, "Unchecked");
                  }


        }
        protected void Unnamed_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < dt_ViewAccessLog.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                Response.Write(dt_ViewAccessLog.Rows[i][0].ToString() +"            "+ dt_ViewAccessLog.Rows[i][1].ToString() +"             "+ dt_ViewAccessLog.Rows[i][2].ToString()+"----");
            }
            HtmlInputCheckBox cb = (HtmlInputCheckBox)form1.FindControl("0 Check");
            if (cb != null && cb.Checked)
            {
                Response.Write("Done...");
            }
        }
```

Comment: You can use $(':checkbox').on('change', function () {...});
inside this function use $.ajax for insert into DataBase

Comment: so how can I change values of asp control i.e Datatable in this function ? I want datatable values to be modified Bases on checked or uncheked events

Comment: Sorry i have mistake - why dont use asp:DataList or asp:GridView for creating some checkbox?

Comment: No I cant use them because I am adding columns dynamically by placing th in a loop not rows!!!